# Python2: Importing same function from multiple files

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using Python 2.7 and I am making a simple grader in Python. What this grader does is following:

1. Iterates over all the folders and imports the folder as a module by adding **init**.py
2. Run one of the methods and compare the output to a predefined output
3. If the output is same then assign True as result else False
4. Move to the next student and import his/her code again

Now all the students have the same file name 'test.py' and the same function name - let's say add

My ISSUE - It seems like when Python imports from the method from the first student's code, it is being carried the same for other students as well.

Sample Code

```
## get the output of the function
output = 5

subdirectories = "contains the directory where all student codes are"

# find python files inside each directory
# copy the init file and run the code
c = 0
for student in subdirectories:
    copyfile(src, os.path.join(student,'__init__.py')) # to make the folder a package
    os.chdir(student)

    from test import * # test is the file name

    # this line below evaluates the same function again and again instead of importing the new method from a different student file
    output_student = eval( functionName + '('+functionArguments+')')
```

Question - How can I import a method with the same name from multiple Python files, each time overwriting the function definition.

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea. I think you should go back to the drawing board. If you need each student to implement a specific function, which you then execute in a generic context, maybe it should be the other way around. i.e. you implement a function which is called passing in each student specific function (i.e strategy pattern). Then there is no need for what you are proposing.

Comment: then how come I can check what their outputs are and then compare to what I should have.

Comment: so functionName is something like 'add', 'subtract' etc. This I am taking via the command line. functionArguments I am taking in the script.

Answer (score 0):

I think [import_module()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) will do what you want.

```
from importlib import import_module
...
module = import_module(<module_to_import>)
output_student = module.functionName(functionArguments)
```